# Sharepoint 2007 Client access of files

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, ms-office

I am trying to gain access of files within specific folders in Sharepoint 2007 from the client side. I am being told that this isn't possible, but when you have a file open from within the folder you can check in and check out the file, so obviously you are able to access the site from the client side. My question is, if I create a excel add in, am I able to open up another file within the Sharepoint site, and get the contents such as, versions and what not?
Has anyone done this before?
Thanks for any help, or links.

Comment: I am not sure if it is what you are asking for, but you should check Sharepoint Web Services

Comment: I am just trying to see if it is at least possible and what I would need to do to make it possible or if it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to get files (regular HTTP GET on document's Url) and obtain most properties of the documents and list items using SharePoint web services - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390(v=office.12).aspx .